situation when group action is properly discontinuous, Allen Hatcher's exercise 1.B.1.
Suppose a group G acts simplicially on a Δ-complex X, where "simplicially" means that each element of G takes each simplex of X onto another simplex by a linear homeomorphism. If the action is free, is it necessarily a covering space action?
I apologize for repeating the question, but a similar question was answered inaccurately and I cannot leave a comment due to lack of rating.
The answer was:
Yes, it is a covering space action, i.e. it is properly discontinuous (see the comment of @Dan). To see why, consider p∈X
and let σ
be the unique simplex whose interior contains p
. The subgroup of G
that preserves σ
is trivial, because that subgroup stabilizes the barycenter of σ
and the action is free. So we can pick a subset U⊂σ
which contains p
, is open in σ
, and whose closure σ¯
is contained in the interior of σ
. This subset U
is disjoint from all its translates by nontrivial elements of G
, because the interior of σ
is disjoint from all its translates.
Using the metric given by barycentric coordinates in each simplex having σ
as a face, it's not hard now to find an open subset V⊃U
of G
which is disjoint from all its translates. For instance, consider each simplex τ1
having σ
as a codimension 1 face. Let V∩τ1
be the ϵ1
-neighborhood of σ
where the constant ϵ1>0
is chosen so small that the closure of V∩τ1
is disjoint from its images under the symmetric group acting on the vertices of τ
. Now proceed up through the skeleta of X
, choosing appropriate constants ϵk
for the simplexes containing σ
as a codimension k
face.
But this proof breaks down at the following statement: consider p∈X and let σ be the unique simplex whose interior contains p,because if p is a vertex, such a simplex may not exist. Even if we omit this point, the second paragraph of the proof remains unclear: it is not clear what kind of simplex τ is, why we are looking for a neighborhood σ on which the symmetry group of this simplex acts freely, and why such a neighborhood exists at all: we can take elements of the symmetry group that rotate σ and then any neighborhood of σ will intersect with its image under the action of such an element of the symmetry group. Further induction is accordingly also unclear.
Link of original question: If the action is free, is it necessarily a covering space action?

If $p$ is a vertex, then the unique simplex containing $p$ in its interior is ${p}$. Every point of a $\Delta$-complex is contained in the interior of a unique simplex. If $n$ is the dimension of this simplex, the $U$ in the first paragraph is an open neighborhood of $p$ in the $n$-skeleton $X_n$ that is disjoint from all its translates under the $G$-action. The point of the second paragraph is to upgrade this to a neighborhood $V$ of $p$ in $X$ that is disjoint from all its translates under the $G$-action. Also, you really should provide a link to where that argument is from.

@Thorgott, thank you, you clarified some of the questions, the link was added, but tell me how to build neighborhood V?

@Thorgott, It seems to me that we can construct V one by one in the following way: for each n+1-dimensional simplex τ1 containing σ as a face, we define V∩τ1 as a neighborhood U whose closure lies in the union of the interiors of τ1 and σ and, in addition, V∩τ1∩σ=U. Thus V∩sk^(n+1)(X) will be an open neighborhood of p in sk^n(X), since its intersection with each skeleton sk^i(X), where i is not greater than n+ 1, is open.Moving inductively through all simplices containing σ as a k-dimensional subsimplex, we obtain an open neighborhood V, on which G acts properly discontinuously, is this right?

That's not quite enough. In Lee Mosher's answer, a point is made to choose $V$ small enough so that the neighborhood is disjoint from its translates under the action of the symmetric group on the vertices. I suggest you draw an example like the antipodal action on the circle (considered as a complex with $2$ $0$-cells and $2$ $1$-cells).

Yes, I forgot to mention that I also require from V∩τ1 that the images of this neighborhood do not intersect under the action of a subgroup of the symmetry group τ1 whose elements act non-trivially on the face σ. Please note that for the symmetry group such a neighborhood may not exist, since the point p may be at the barycenter σ and then the elements that rotate σ act on the neighborhood with intersections. In our case, such actions cannot take place, since simplexes do not form into themselves.
